# Printing Webpage format with only minor print.css

Tags: html, css, printing

Ever feel like you've been making webstuff for so long you're starting to forget things you learned ages ago?

I'm trying to remember a declaration of some sort that you put at the top of a print.css that takes the normal format .css of a page for printing. (and of course, applies the few display:none that I've added in the printcss)

I just can't remember what to search for. help?

does it have to do with display:block?

Comment: Are you talking about [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)? IE, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="serif.css">` or `@media print {/*cool print-only stuff*/}`.

Comment: the normal css is media screen and the print is media print.

Comment: I'm not following what you're asking about. Maybe `@import`?

Comment: If you're trying to manipulate a page that displays in a web browser for a printer, setup your regular css files to have no `media` attribute/target, and then have a `print.css` that's included that is `media="print"` only that backs off/hides what you're looking to change on print.

Comment: hmm. no, not @import. I'm using a lot of css in my main.css file. like inline li's for column formatting and such, and I want to make sure it prints like that.

Comment: And you have two linked stylesheets, one with `media="screen"` and one with `media="print"`? If so, remove the `media="screen"` and let it apply to the print job, with the print stylesheet canceling/removing/modifying what it needs to. Otherwise, I don't know what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">`

**Here's an example of a print stylesheet**

```
body { background: #fff; width: 80%; margin: auto; padding: 5%; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { color: #333; }
p { font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; }
a { color: #243D8D; }
.post img { display: block; float: left; margin: 15px 15px 15px 0; }
```

Your main goal is to increase readability. So write your CSS in a way that makes that happen.

Comment: I understand how to make a basic print.css , I'm trying to maintain layout formatting from main.css. Does the cascade still apply?